# How to copy the latest modified files between two servers

Tags: batch-file, server

Everyday at 1 am some zip folders will come in on one server(let us say A).  I need to copy the files to another server(let us say B). After copying the files to server B, then after some time the copied files will moves to another destination. For the next day the previously copied files should not come with the files from today.

Now, the problem is, it is working fine in my Local PC .. It is not working in the server.

I don't have knowledge of batch file programming. Please let me know if there is a way to accomplish this.

My code:

```
@echo off
forfiles /s /p "\\10.35.0.44\Da\Ra\Folder" /m "*.zip" /d +"02/04/2019" /c "cmd /c move @path \\10.35.0.44\Da\sai"
pause
```

It is the throwing following error:

```
Error:UNC paths <\\machine\share> are not supported
```

Because of this I've used `pushD()popD`. The error was not there but the files are not being copied.

Comment: You said you are using `PUSHD` and `POPD` but your code still reflects that you are not using them nor did you change your `FORFILES` command to reflect that you are using them.

Comment: I would also advise you to not use `FORFILES` for this task and use `ROBOCOPY` instead.